# Repeat python function and return value

Tags: python

I am trying to have a function repeat itself if a certain criteria is not met. For instance:

```
def test():
    print "Hello",
    x = raw_input()
    if x in '0123456789':
        return x
    test()
```

In this program if you type a number the first time, it will return the number. If you type some non-number, it will repeat itself as desired. However, if you type some non-numbers and then a number, it will return nothing. Why is that the case?

Comment: It should work if you replace `test()` with `return test()`.

Comment: If you want to repeat a prompt until you get valid input I'd suggest using a while loop rather than recursion. Every time the input is invalid you get another frame pushed on the stack. Probably not a big deal for what you're doing, but no harm in being tidy.

Comment: @cjm, if what you're doing is "learning to program" it is a big deal. But mistakes can be a _good thing_ if you learn from them.

Answer (score 8):

you need to `return test()` at the tail of the function to return the value that the valid call into test() returns.

Answer (score 4):

The way you are having test call itself is the wrong way to do it. Each time your program restarts the function, you will use up another level of stack. Eventually the program will stop(crash) even if the user never inputs one of those characters.

```
def test():
    while True:
        print "Hello",
        x = raw_input()
        if x in '0123456789':
            return x
```

Comment: You know you are right, and you know the code you posted is simply not fun. :-) But, the code will work the way the o.p. envisioned - for this purpose - @mikecorcoran's answer has the real problem nailed.